# Is a differentiable function $g(x)$ a strictly increasing function iff $g'(x)>0$?

Tags: calculus

Yes, I think a differentiable function $g(x)$ is a strictly increasing function if and only if $g'(x)>0$, but I am not sure why.

Is there a theorem for it?

I informally know that if $g(x)$ is differentiable and $g'(x)>0$, then the $g(x)$ is strictly increasing. And if $g(x)$ is differentiable and $g'(x)<0$, then the $g(x)$ is strictly decreasing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $g(x) = x^3$ is strictly increasing and satisfies $g'(0) = 0$.

If a function $g$ is (not necessarily strictly) increasing and differentiable, then $g'(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$. This is a direct consequence of the definition of the derivative.

Comment: Can we adjust the claim, perhaps in the following way: If $g$ is strictly increasing and differentiable everwhere, does it then follow that $g'(x)>0$ in all points except for countably many $x$ where $g'(x) = 0$? 

By the way +1.

Comment: @Eff We can adjust the claim in the following way: If $g$ is differentiable, then the set $\{x \mid g'(x) = 0\}$ has empty interior. I'm not sure whether your version holds aswell. I don't see an obvious solution, so it might be an interesting question to ask.

Comment: I don't think you require MVT to prove that "$g$ is (strictly) increasing and differentiable $\Rightarrow g'(x) \geq 0$". Just the definition of derivative suffices. MVT is required (but not necessarily so) to prove the implication in the other direction.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh You're right, I've adjusted my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a strictly increasing $C^1$ function on $\mathbb {R}$ whose derivative $=0$ on an uncountable set: Let $K$ denote the Cantor set. For $x\in \mathbb R,$ set $g(x) = d(x,K).$ Then $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb {R}, g = 0$ on $K,$ and $g>0$ on $\mathbb {R}\setminus K.$

Set $G(x) = \int_0^xg.$ Then $G'=g$ everywhere by the FTC, which implies $G' = 0$ on $K,$ an uncountable set. To see that $G$ is strictly increasing, recall that $\mathbb {R}\setminus K$ is dense in $\mathbb {R}.$  Thus if $x<y,$ $g$ will be positive somewhere in between, hence positive on an interval of positive length contained in $(x,y),$ hence $G(y)-G(x) = \int_x^yg >0.$

Comment: A nice example! What if we demand $g$ to be twice differentiable or even smooth?

Comment: Heh, thanks for answering my subquestion, +1.

Comment: @Dominik Not much difference. You can replace the distance with a smooth bump function in the definition.